# Find the PDF of a stochastic process $X(t,\xi) = \xi \cos(2\pi t)$ at fixed $t$

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $\xi \sim \text{Unif}[-1,1]$  and a random process be given as $ X(t,\xi) = \xi \cos(2\pi t)$

I am required to find the PDF of $X(t) := X(t,\xi)$ at:

a) at time $t = 1/4$

b) at time $t = 1$

I need help because none of my solutions make sense!

---

Here are my attempts:

Let $F_{X(t)}(x) = \Pr[X(t) \leq x] = \Pr[\xi \cos(2\pi t) \leq x] $

a) Suppose that $t = 1/4$, we have $F_{X(1/4)}(x) = \Pr[X(1/4) \leq x] = \Pr[\xi  \leq \dfrac{x}{\lim\limits_{t \to 1/4} \cos(2\pi t)}]  = \Pr[\xi \leq \infty] = 1$ since $\cos(\pi/2) = 0$

Then $f_{X(1/4)}(x) = \dfrac{dF(x)}{dx} = 0$. The limiting argument seems wrong, please assist.

b) Suppose that $t = 1$, we have $F_{X(1)}(x) = \Pr[X(1) \leq x] = \Pr[\xi  \leq \dfrac{x}{\lim\limits_{t \to 1} \cos(2\pi t)}]  = \Pr[\xi \leq x]$

Then $f_{X(1)}(x) = \dfrac{dF_{X(1)}(x)}{dx} = \dfrac{d\Pr[\xi \leq x]}{d\xi}\dfrac{d\xi}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d\xi}{dx}  $ where we used the chain rule

But what is $\dfrac{d\xi}{dx}$??

Any assistance helps, I'm just starting out.

Comment: Hints: $X(\frac 14) = \xi\cdot 0 = 0$ regardless of the value of $\xi$. $X(1) = \xi\cdot 1 = \xi$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I see, so $X(1/4) = 0$ places all probability on $0$ only and no where else. A Kronecker delta. And $X(1) = \xi$, so $X(1)$ has the same distribution as $\xi$. Thanks!!! But still funny the usual approach doesn't work

Comment: @StackexchangeHouseNinja $X(1/4)$ is the RV $0$ (which is a constant, so not actually random). Its PDF is not a Kronecker delta, but rather a Dirac delta. And you're right about $X(1)$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Dirac delta has amplitude $\infty$ at $x = 0$ no?

Comment: @StackexchangeHouseNinja It does in a sense, but it's complicated. It can be roughtly thought of as a function with all its 'area' isolated at the point zero. And you need infinite height to get a finite area out of an infinitesimal width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dilip's hints in the comments are absolutely the right way to think about the problem.

It may also be useful to understand where your attempts went wrong. For part (a) you said $\frac{x}{\lim_{t\to 1/4} \cos(2\pi t)} = \infty$ but that's not right. The limit is $+\infty$ from one side and $-\infty$ from the other.

For part (b) note that $\xi$ is not a variable but rather a random variable and has no dependence on $x.$ So it doesn't make sense to write $\frac{d\xi}{dx.}$ Since $\xi$ is random $P(\xi \le x)$ means "the probability that $\xi$ turns out to be less than or equal to $x$" which is a number that depends on $x.$ This function of $x$ is just the CDF of $\xi,$ which recall is a $U(-1,1).$ The PDF is indeed the derivative of the CDF, but that just means when you differentiate this CDF you will get the PDF of $\xi,$ i.e. the PDF of a $U(-1,1),$ which takes the value $1/2$ on the interval $(-1,1)$ and zero elsewhere.

Comment: I see where I went wrong with the second one. Thanks!!

Comment: So it is inappropriate to write $\dfrac{d\Pr[\xi \leq x]}{dx}$ since $\Pr[\xi \leq x]$ is a probability. However, notationally $F_\xi(x)  = \Pr[\xi \leq x]$, and  $\dfrac{dF_\xi(x)}{dx}$ are often used. Is there some sort of a paradox going on here If we cannot write  $\dfrac{d\Pr[\xi \leq x]}{dx}$ then certainly we cannot write $\dfrac{dF_\xi(x)}{dx}$ either...

Comment: It is totally fine to write $ \frac{d}{dx}Pr(\xi \le x)$ since $Pr(\xi\le x)$ is a function of $x$ (I never said it wasn't). What's not okay is to write $\frac{d}{d\xi}P(\xi \le x) $ or $\frac{dx}{d\xi}$ or $\frac{d\xi}{dx}.$